# Seaborn clustermap dendrogram color

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to change my clustermaps dendrogram color from black to "white"

i dont want to color each class with different colors , rather a reproducible function that can just change the dendrograms to white

Code

```
import seaborn as sns 
DATA=sns.load_dataset("tips")           
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                 
plt.figure()      
sns.set_style(style="white")
              
ax=sns.clustermap(DATA.corr(), 
cmap="viridis")
             
plt.savefig("clustermap",transparent=True)
```

Comment: You can use the `tree_kws` to change the appearance of the dendogram lines.  E.g. `g = sns.clustermap(data.corr(), cmap="viridis", tree_kws={'color': 'white'})`. Also note that `sns.clustermap` is a figure-level function that doesn't return an `ax`, but a `ClusterGrid` instance.

Comment: It works very well !

Comment: Is there any Similar keyword for changing pairplot label color as well..??

Comment: Which pairplot? Which label? Maybe you want to set some rcParams?